# ExtJS TypeError: item.onAdded is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I build a simple UI using ExtJS 4. I have created two view classes called `Main` and `Menu` which are inside the view folder. after that I included those classes as following way. But I met an error. `TypeError: item.onAdded is not a function` was printed in the console. here my code

**Main.js**

```
Ext.define('Ext1.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires:[
        'Ext.tab.Panel',
        'Ext.layout.container.Border'
    ],
    items : [
        {
            xtype : 'menume'
        }
    ]
});
```

**Menu.js**

```
Ext.define('Ext1.view.Menu',{
    alias : 'widget.menume',
      title: 'User Form',
    height: 150,
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'firstName'
        },
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            name: 'lastName'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
            name: 'birthDate'
        }
    ]
});
```

**Application.js**

```
Ext.define('Ext1.Application', {
    name: 'Ext1',

    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    views: [
       'Ext1.view.Menu', 'Ext1.view.Main'
    ],

    controllers: [
        // TODO: add controllers here
    ],

    stores: [
        // TODO: add stores here
    ]
});
```

Why I have got that error?

Answer (score 3):

Because `Ext1.view.Menu` doesn't extend anything. It needs to be (to have items) a container, at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('Ext1.view.Menu',{
    extend: 'Ext.menu.Menu'// add this
    alias : 'widget.menume',
      title: 'User Form',
    height: 150,
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'firstName'
        },
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            name: 'lastName'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
            name: 'birthDate'
        }
    ]
});
```